# Undefined reference error for static constexpr member

Tags: c++, definition, constexpr, c++17

Consider this code:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct A {
  static constexpr int kDefaultValue = -1;
  std::vector<int> v;
  A(int n): v(n, A::kDefaultValue) {}
};

int main() {
  A(10);
  return 0;
}
```

It fails to link (llvm clang, gcc 4.9, both on OS X):

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "A::kDefaultValue", referenced from:
      A::(int) in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The question is what's wrong with it? It can be fixed by `static_cast`-ing `A::kDefaultValue` to `int`. Or by moving `kDefaultValue` out of `A`. Both cases seem to be ugly. Is this another way to make it link?

Comment: Use a compiler supporting C++17.

Comment: what are you trying to do here ->  `A(int n): v(n, A::kDefaultValue)` Why no  just do `A(int n): v(n,)` ? and use std=c++11 as compiler option

Comment: songyuanyao: tried gcc-6 with c++14, c++17, same thing.

Comment: @y0prst It's fine with gcc7. http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/izFx4rwqLyX8QR7x

Comment: @solti: All I want is vector of `-1`-s and also I want to take name to this `-1` constant. `-std=c++11` does not help, as well as `c++14` and `c++17`.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Nice! I wonder what was changed in c++17 in order to make this code work. Don't believe that this is just a compiler bug :)

Comment: @y0prst It's not a bug, the behavior changed from C++17. See my answer for details.

Comment: Another _workaround_ is to change `kDefaultValue` to `static constexpr std::integral_constant<int, -1> kDefaultValue{};`. No external definition is needed and `v(n, A::kDefaultValue)` will work correctly, and it works for C++11 onwards. [Online Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/602086f995f56e53)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This behaviour is vexing me time and again. The cause of the trouble is that your

```
A(int n): v(n, A::kDefaultValue) {}
```

[**odr-uses**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) the `static constexpr` member, since the constructor of `v` takes a constant reference second argument. Odr-usage requires a definition somewhere, i.e.

```
const int A::kDefaultValue;
```

in some compilation unit (which is compiled and linked to `main()`). This requirement has been dropped in C++17 and the corresponding definition (as above) deprecated.

However, a definition is not always possible (for example for members of class templates) and the simplest way to avoid both the definition and your error is

```
A(int n): v(n, int(A::kDefaultValue)) {}
```

which creates a temporary to be passed to the constructor of `v` (but since the latter is fully inline, the compiler may optimise that away).

Comment: Is it worth to use constexpr method instead of static member? `static constexpr int default_value() { return -1; };` Seems it works in all standards with no drawbacks.

Comment: Yes, that's another possibility; and with all these things it's a matter of taste and style. The standard library uses `static` members in its [numeric_limits<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) traits classes.

Comment: BTW, it's strange, that for example using `numeric_limits<int>::radix`, which is `static constexpr` member of `struct numeric_limits`, does not fail.

Comment: @y0prst That's because implementations of the standard library provide a definition of these static variables somewhere (which the linker then finds).

Answer (score 14):

The behavior changed since C++17. Before C++17, even a [constexpr static data member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members) must be initialized inside the class definition, definition at namespace scope is still required; Since C++17 the namespace scope definition is not required again.

> If a static data member is declared constexpr, it is implicitly inline and does not need to be redeclared at namespace scope. This redeclaration without an initializer (formerly required as shown above) is still permitted, but is deprecated. (since C++17)

Compiling your code with a compiler supporting C++17 would work fine.

[LIVE demo with gcc7](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/izFx4rwqLyX8QR7x)