# static constexpr undefined reference error on clang

Tags: c++, clang, constexpr

The following code compiles fine on Visual Studio 2019 and on gcc 10.2 (and other gcc versions) with `-std=c++11` but fails on clang (versions 9, 10 and 11).

```cpp
#include <map>
#include <string>

struct repo {
    static constexpr const char *x = "sth";
};

int main() {

    // 1) This compiles
    std::map<std::string, int> m1 = { {repo::x, 3} };
    
    // 2) This compiles
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m2 = { std::make_pair(repo::x, "") };
    
    // 3) This does not compile on clang
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m3 = { {repo::x, ""} };

    return 0;
}
```

The error from clang is:

```
... undefined reference to `repo::x'
clang-11: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Compiler returned: 1
```

There are similar questions on SO on this, i.e. *Undefined reference error, static constexpr data member*, but none that explain to me why this code does not compile on clang. Is there an issue with the code in `3)` above?

Comment: very related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40690260/undefined-reference-error-for-static-constexpr-member

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks, I was reading that before posting but I think this is different. For example, `1)` compiles on clang but `3)` does not. If the linked answer was the issue, neither should compile for that reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C++17 introduces the rule that `static constexpr` member variables are implicitly `inline` ([P0386](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0386r2.pdf)).  Inline variables didn't exist before C++17.

This means that in earlier C++ standards, a compiler **may** need a `static constexpr` member variable to be defined.  If its address is taken, for example.

In C++ standards earlier than C++17, you can ensure that your code is well-formed, by separately **defining** the `static` variable.

```
struct repo {
    static constexpr const char *x = "sth";
};

constexpr const char *repo::x;
```

***Edit:***

It should be noted that with **optimizations off**, [none](https://godbolt.org/z/dKev4K) of the [examples](https://godbolt.org/z/YWvn43) successfully link.

It is an artifact of the optimizer that *sometimes*, a reference to a value can be flattened to the value itself, in which case the linker won't look for the missing symbol.

Comment: Doesn't explain why in this particular example definition is required.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Why does `std::map<std::string, int> m1 = { {repo::x, 3} };` compile fine yet `std::map<std::string, std::string> m3 = { {repo::x, ""} };` fails to compile. If it is an issue regarding the implicit inlining of `repo::x`, should this not equally affect the compilation of the line `std::map<std::string, int> m1 = { {repo::x, 3} };`?

Comment: @Francis I have added an _edit_ that addresses what you mention.

Comment: @DrewDormann Thanks a lot. I am marking this as answer. This was the piece that was really confusing me. I never thought to remove the optimisation flag when playing around on https://godbolt.org.

Answer (score 2):

Using https://godbolt.org/z/edj6Ed I verified that the program compiles & runs for gcc >= 7, but fails with the same error as your clang for 6.4, **provided that one uses**

```
-std=c++17
```

(actually I used `-pedantic -std=c++17`).

Clang++ also compiles your program fine starting from version 5.0.0, the first to support C++17. It always fails with `std=C++14`.

What happened in C++17 that refers to `static constexpr`?

> A constexpr specifier used in a function or static member variable (since C++17) declaration implies inline.

(see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr )

See also: https://www.codingame.com/playgrounds/2205/7-features-of-c17-that-will-simplify-your-code/inline-variables

Comment: Thanks. However, I don't see this failing to compile on gcc versions >=7. For example, the following link shows compilation with gcc 10.2 and `-O2 -pedantic -std=c++17` e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/oWKhhs.

Comment: Additionally, I would have the same comment as I added to the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65999633/1771882 below. If the failure is due to implicit inlining of `repo::x`, should this not cause an error from `1)` also i.e. the line `std::map<std::string, int> m1 = { {repo::x, 3} };`.

Comment: I'm not good at godbolot.org, but I think its primary purpose is to compile and disassembly a program, and for this linking is unnecessary. See this: https://godbolt.org/z/oq6cdd there's a third panel which tries to run the program and then all attempts with gcc  and `-std=c++14` fail. It also fails on my machine if I use this flag manually, but I have an alias `g++='g++ -std=c++17'`, which made me think gcc behaves different than clang, for which I have no alias and which I use only occasionally. No. Gcc also reports an error.

Answer (score 2):

Pre-C++17, you need to have a definition of `static constexpr` variable if it is [ODR-used](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#:%7E:text=A%20function%20is%20odr%2Dused%20if%20it%20is%20named%20by,required%20to%20construct%20the%20vtable).

In your example, `x` is ODR-used, since it is passed to as an argument to `pair` constructor, which takes values by reference. Thus, you need a definition for it.

Comment: Thanks. I have to admit that I am not very clear on when a variable is ODR-used or not. Is `x` not ODR-used in the statement `std::map<std::string, int> m1 = { {repo::x, 3} };` also? If it is, shouldn't compilation fail when only this part is included i.e. `2)` and `3)` are removed?